# My automated converter multiplies the converted files in python

Tags: python

my name is Luis and I have programmed a small script that converts all normal files in folders and sub-folders to the bz2 format and my problem is that it converts the converted files multiple times. For example if I convert my two files there are now four files and two of them have been converted twice, so: file.bz2.bz2. And I tried to fix it but I didn't get it to work. Thanks for the help.

### Main.py

```py
import os
import subprocess
from progress.bar import ChargingBar

data_folder, total = r"C:\Users\luisb\Auto_Packer_Gmod\d", 0

def convert(filename):
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
subprocess.run(f"packany.bat {filename}", stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    for entry in listOfFile:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    result = [val for val in allFiles if not val.endswith("bz2")]
    return result


def packer():
    data = getListOfFiles(data_folder)
    bar = ChargingBar('Processing', max=len(data), suffix = '%(percent).1f%% - %(index)d/%(max)d')

    bar.start()

    for i in data:
        convert(i)
        os.remove(i)
        bar.next()

    bar.finish()

packer()
```

### packany.bat

```
@echo off

for /f %%i in ("%1") do (
    echo %%~di
    echo %%~pi
    echo %%~xi
    set rootpath="%%~di%%~pi*%%~xi"
)

for %%f in (%rootpath%) do (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tbzip2 "%%f.bz2" "%%f" -mx9
)
```

Comment: What does the _rootpath_ end up being in your `packany.bat`? It seems like you are looping over the files found in rootpath, while also looping in the python-script.

Comment: The file is for convertment from file to file.bz2

Comment: Ok. Have you checked out the builtin bz2 library in Python? You are recursively calling your function `getListOfFiles(fullPath)`, might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks it was the rootpath. I am using now the buildin bz2 library and now it works.

Comment: Here is the code if someone needs it '''def convert(filename):
    bz2_data = bz2.compress(open(filename, 'rb').read(), 9)
    with open(filename + '.bz2', 'wb') as b:
        b.write(bz2_data)
        b.close()'''

Comment: If you have found the answer, please post it as an answer and accept it for the benefit of others who may see this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sure here is my Full code:

```
import os
from progress.bar import ChargingBar
import bz2
import re

def convert(filename):
bz2_data = bz2.compress(open(filename, 'rb').read(), 9)
with open(filename + '.bz2', 'wb') as b:
    b.write(bz2_data)
    b.close()

def getListOfFiles(dirName, endswith):
listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
allFiles = list()
for entry in listOfFile:
    fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
        allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath, "all")
    else:
        allFiles.append(fullPath)
if endswith == "no_lua":
    result = [val for val in allFiles if not val.endswith("bz2")]
    return result
if endswith == "no":
    result = [val for val in allFiles if not val.endswith("lua")]
    return result
if endswith == "no_both":
    dat = [val for val in allFiles if not val.endswith("bz2")]
    result = [val for val in dat if not val.endswith("lua")]
    return result
if endswith == "only_lua":
    result = [val for val in allFiles if val.endswith("lua")]
    return result
if endswith == "all":
    return allFiles

def packer(dirName, endswith):
data = getListOfFiles(dirName, endswith)
bar = ChargingBar('Processing', max=len(data), suffix='%(percent).1f%% -(index)d/%(max)d')

bar.start()

for i in data:
    convert(i)
    os.remove(i)
    bar.next()

bar.finish()
```